# Minibuffer and ido keybindings with ergoemacs-mode

Tags: key-bindings, minibuffer, ido, ergoemacs

I'm struggling to get the same hotkeys in the latest ergoemacs-mode (as they were in ergoemacs 5.3.7):

- In the M-x (`execute-extended-command`) command prompt I want `M-i` to act as `previous-line-or-history-element`, and `M-k` as `next-line-or-history-element`
- In the `C-o` (`ergoemacs-find-file`) I want `M-j` to act as `ido-prev-match`, and `M-l` as `ido-next-match`

Tried various things but no success so far.